Add bibitem to biblatex bibliography
I have a journal system where I use latex files for entries with their own bibliographies. I use biblatex with my global bib file which includes all papers and books that I usually cite.
However, sometimes I want to cite a paper for just one entry and I don't want to include it in my library and I prefer not to create a separate file just for it. So I am wondering if there is a way to add a custom bibtem to a biblatex bibliography directly from the tex file. It would be great even I can combine the bibliographies, but even separate ones would be fine.
See the MWE below
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}

  This is a reference from the bib file \cite{angenendt}.

  This one from the the ``local'' bibliography \cite{lamport94}.

  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{lamport94}
    Leslie Lamport (1994) \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system}, Addison
    Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd ed.
  \end{thebibliography}
  \printbibliography

\end{refsection}

\end{document}


I found this answer to a similar problem, and I adapted it to this solution
EDIT: I modified the solution to use the verbatim package, to allow for line breaks and custom characters in the local biblio definition.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter   % Based on moreverb
\def\openverbfile#1#2{
  \@ifundefined{verbatim@out@#1}{\expandafter\newwrite \csname verbatim@out@#1\endcsname}{}%
  \immediate\openout \csname verbatim@out@#1\endcsname #2%
}
\def\verbatimwrite#1{%
  \@bsphack%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\^^M\active \catcode`\^^I=12
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    \immediate\write\csname verbatim@out@#1\endcsname
    {\the\verbatim@line}}%
  \verbatim@start}
\def\endverbatimwrite{%
  \@esphack}
\def\closeverbfile#1{
\immediate\closeout\csname verbatim@out@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\openverbfile{localbib}{local-bibs.bib}
\addbibresource{local-bibs.bib}
\AtEndDocument{\closeverbfile{localbib}}

\def\localbiblio{\verbatimwrite{localbib}}
\def\endlocalbiblio{\endverbatimwrite}


\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}

  This is a reference from the bib file \cite{angenendt}.

  \begin{localbiblio}
    @book{freder:measure,
      title={Geometric measure theory},
      author={Federer, Herbert},
      year={1969},
      publisher={Springer}
    }
  \end{localbiblio}

  This one from the the local bibliography \cite{freder:measure}.
  \printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}


If you don't want to include the entry in your library, what about to use the filecontents environment, like in the next MWE?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{myreflist.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{myreflist.bib}
    @book{lamport94,
        author={Lamport, Leslie},gender={sm},
        title={\LaTeX},
        subtitle={A Document Preparation System},
        publisher={Addison Wesley},location={Reading (\textsc{ma})},
        year={1994},edition={2}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This is a reference from the bib file \cite{angenendt}.

This one from the the ``local'' bibliography \cite{lamport94}.

\printbibliography[heading={bibliography},title={\refname}]
\end{document}

I let a shared reference list.
Yes, in effect, it's almost as if you are creating a separate file just for the document, but I really don't know if there are any easier alternatives.
